# mysql database corrupt -- looking for solution that doesnt require complete dump and load

Tags: mysql

I've ran into a database with a corrupted schema. The data directory folder for this schema has only .frm files (no .ibd files exist). The goal was to drop this database and then recreate, but errors are preventing that from happening.

Solution that has been considered is to dump all the "good" databases, remove the bad files, and then reimport them. I would like to avoid this scenario if possible.

The concern about deleting the data directory is that the ibdata or iblogfiles might have information pertaining to this old defunct schema, so stopping mysql, removing data directory, removing log files and restarting mysql doesn't seem to be a full-proof solution.

Comment: Restore from your most recent backup.

Comment: Im asking if there is a more viable option.

Comment: No, you asked if there was alternative to dumping the *good* databases, removing the bad files, and then reimporting. I offered a viable alternative to what you asked. If you mean to ask something different, then [edit] your question and ask what you really want to ask.